# Python oraciones

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este problema:
a='thissentencemakesperfectsense'
es una oración y necesito dividir las palabras de tal forma que quede asi.

this sentence makes perfect sense

He intentado con diccionarios pero es en casos en particular, no se como hacer para que python divida cada palabra y mas que reconozca todas las palabras de una oracion.

Alguna idea?
Gracias

Comment: Creo que podrías usar Python NLTK. No lo he usado, pero se que lo usan para procesamiento de lenguaje natural. Mas info acá: http://www.nltk.org/

Comment: Dale un vistazo a esta publicación (en inglés): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words

Comment: Vale gracias amigo!